# How Can I create wings with auto rig pro

Tags: rigging, auto-rig-pro

I've read the Auto rig pro documentation and I saw you can make wing rig with it from the limb options, but I tried I couldn't see any wing options there. Is there something I'm supposed to activate before then?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that my Auto Rig Pro was just outdated

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/110065)

Comment: @Nate_Sycro27 this is a perfectly valid answer

Answer (score 0):

The wings rig is not a separate limb option on its own, rather it is an option on the arms limb rig.

See http://lucky3d.fr/auto-rig-pro/doc/auto_rig.html?#wings

Comment: I'm well aware of that, its just that I dont see any option like that when I go to limb options for the arms